Bidirectional conversion between enum and string in C
I am building an application with a lot of integer values which need to be mapped to strings for user CLI and logging.
Using array LUT does not provide boundary checks so I want to generate conversion functions to make sure invalid values will be handled properly.
The idea is to use a function like this:
void *enumStr(void *e, bool isToStr) 
{
  if (isToStr && e == NUM_ZERO) return "zero"; if (!isToStr && strcmp(e, "zero") == 0) return 0;
  if (isToStr && e == NUM_ONE)  return "one";  if (!isToStr && strcmp(e, "one") == 0) return 1;
  if (isToStr && e == NUM_TWO)  return "two";  if (!isToStr && strcmp(e, "two") == 0) return 2;
  if (isToStr) return "ENUM_N/A"; else return UINT_MAX; 
}

which converts between a number and a string and to add two helper functions which hide the boolean argument.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>


#define ENUMSTR_START(enumName)  \
    void * _ ## enumName ## _(void *e, bool isToStr) {
    
#define ENUMSTR_ITEM(enumItem, enumStr) \
    if (isToStr && e == enumItem) return enumStr; if (!isToStr && strcmp(e, enumStr) == 0) return enumItem

#define ENUMSTR_END(enumName) \
    if (isToStr) return "STR_N/A"; else return UINT_MAX; } \
    const char * enumName ## _toStr(uint32_t enumItem) { return (const char * ) _ ## enumName ## _ (enumItem, true); } \
    uint32_t enumName ## _fromStr(const char *enumStr)  { return _ ## enumName ## _ (enumStr, false); }

typedef enum
{
    NUM_ZERO,
    NUM_ONE,
    NUM_TWO
} NUM;

ENUMSTR_START(NUM)
    ENUMSTR_ITEM(NUM_ZERO, "zero");
    ENUMSTR_ITEM(NUM_ONE, "one");
    ENUMSTR_ITEM(NUM_TWO, "two");
ENUMSTR_END(NUM)


int main(void) {
    printf("test 0 %s\n", NUM_toStr(NUM_ZERO));
    printf("test 1 %s\n", NUM_toStr(NUM_ONE));
    printf("test 2 %s\n", NUM_toStr(NUM_TWO));
    printf("test 32 %s\n", NUM_toStr(32));

    printf("test zero %u\n", NUM_fromStr("zero"));
    printf("test one %u\n", NUM_fromStr("one"));
    printf("test two %u\n", NUM_fromStr("two"));
    printf("test three %u\n", NUM_fromStr("three"));

    return 0;
}

Output:
test 0 zero
test 1 one
test 2 two
test 32 STR_N/A
test zero 0
test one 1
test two 2
test three 4294967295


Returning 1 from the function void *enumStr(void *e, bool isToStr) is not valid C as arbitrary integer values cannot certainly convert to a void *.  You need a new approach.  Please explain more about your needs and usage limitations.

"mapped to strings" --> what will be the longest string?  Is it unbounded?

@chux-ReinstateMonica can you explain more about void*? Can't I assign any value I want to a pointer?

@chux-ReinstateMonica About the needs: I have a lot of enums which must be associated with strings so that I can convert strings from user input to enums and convert enums to strings when writing log messages.

"lot of enums" --> 10s 1000s 10000s of them?  String lengths, what range? 0, 1, 10, 100 1000?

@chux-ReinstateMonica 30 enums, up to 20 chars string length

Macro names are all-caps - that's conventional and good.
Enum values are also all-caps - that makes them look like macros, which is not good.


#define ENUMSTR_START(enumName)  \
    void * _ ## enumName ## _(void *e, bool isToStr) {


This appears to create a function whose name begins with _ - that's not good, as all such names are reserved for the implementation.  Even worse when enumName begins with a capital letter, as this could collide with macros!

I don't like the single function switching between conversions.  Is there really a use-case where we decide which direction to convert at run-time?
Much better to define a pair of functions, one for each direction of conversion - enumName str_to_enumName(const char*) and const char* enumName_to_str(enumName).

This is a standard use case for an X-macro, where we define a macro that can apply another macro to each of the members of the enum:
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define X_ENUM_VALUE(v, s) v,
#define X_TO_STR(v, s) case v: return s;
#define X_FROM_STR(v, s) if (!strcmp(x, s)) { return v; }

#define MAKE_ENUM(X, name)                      \
                                                \
typedef enum {                                  \
   X(X_ENUM_VALUE)                              \
} name;                                         \
                                                \
const char *name##_to_str(name x)               \
{                                               \
    switch(x) {                                 \
        X(X_TO_STR)                             \
        default: return "ENUM_N/A";             \
    }                                           \
}                                               \
                                                \
name str_to_##name(const char* x)               \
{                                               \
    X(X_FROM_STR)                               \
    return UINT_MAX;                            \
}

Then for each enum, we just need something like
#define ENUM_NUM(DO) \
   DO(num_zero, "Zero") \
   DO(num_one, "One") \
   DO(num_two, "Two") \

MAKE_ENUM(ENUM_NUM, num)

Simple demo of the above:
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", num_to_str(num_one));
    printf("%d\n", str_to_num("Two"));
}

